# Which D&D edition is this board game inspired from?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

Recently, a coworker told me they have started playing D&D with friends and they have shown me pictures of their gaming materials... and they really look like one of those introductory D&D tabletop games: character sheets on colorful cardboard, a foldable grid with built-in walls riddled with miniatures, etc.

I don't have access to the photo and I think this stack is more qualified at answering my question than boardgames, and that is entirely because the character sheets pictured Jozan and Mialee, two of the 3rd edition iconics, and they looked exactly like they look in the PHB for D&D 3e or 3.5e in the classes chapter.

I suppose the iconics never appeared in other editions - 4e didn't have them and I've never handled 2e player manuals but I think the pictures were in black and white there.

**Am I right in saying that the presence of the iconics strongly suggests that this is a 3e or 3.5e era boardgame?**

If identifying the exact version of the boardgame is important, The two sheets were in portrait orientation, had spaces for tracking level and HP using a token to mark the current one at the two sides and the two I saw had blue and yellow backgrounds if my memory serves me well.

I think I have seen cards around the character sheet, probably to track equipment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It appears to me from your description that they are playing [Dungeons & Dragons: The Fantasy Adventure Board Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/6366/dungeons-dragons-fantasy-adventure-board-game) first released in 2003.

- 5e was released in 2014
- 4e was released in 2008
- 3.5 was released in 2003
- 3e was released in 2000

The logo on the box of the Dungeons & Dragons: The Fantasy Adventure Board Game is the one used in 3/3.5 pretty much solidifying your guess of 3/3.5 era.  More importantly, they are not playing Dungeons and Dragons, per se, but a board game based on it.

Comment: Well found, it's that one. Wikipedia says it was first released in 2002 so 3e it is.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct that Jozan and Mialee only appear in 3.*x* materials. They were original Wizards of the Coast creations and did not appear in D&D material prior to 3e. “Mialee” is suggested as a female elf name in 4e and 5e, and the cover of *Tales from the Yawning Portal* for 5e appears to depict Jozan and Mialee (among several others), but they aren’t named anywhere in the book.

I know nothing of the board game in question, but as for the question “Which D&D edition is this board game inspired from?” the answer is most certainly 3.*x*.